# How to add and run a Glance to an existing Apple Watch app?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos-2

I have an existing Apple Watch app in my iOS project.

How can I add a Glance to the existing project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending many hours i got solution.
@gyer, you was correct for adding Glance in existing project but that was not complete solution.

As per [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/TheGlanceController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH16-SW1) i have created Glance interface.

The main issue was there how to Run Glance after adding it?

There you need to add Scheme like shown in attached image:

1. Tap on Running Target
2. Choose Edit Scheme
3. Duplicate Apple Watch App scheme and Give new name for Glance like shown in attached image,
4. Choose Glance from Watch Interface like shown in attached image,
5. That's it, now choose new created Glance Scheme and Run...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to edit the scheme of an existing target, although you certainly can.

If you already have your Apple Watch target setup and added to an existing app, and simply want to add and build a Glance view, you can follow the steps at [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/TheGlanceController.html).

Apple Watch apps are heavily controlled by interface builder. Adding a new (only add one!) **Glance Interface Controller** to your storyboard and **specifying the custom class name** is adequate; Apple Watch will load your glance interface controller automatically.

1. Add a new *Glance Interface Controller* to your storyboard:

   [image]
2. Add a new file to your extension, named e.g. `GlanceInterfaceController.swift`, ensuring that it's a member of your extension:

   [image]

   [image]
3. Your new `GlanceInterfaceController.swift` should be a subclass of `WKInterfaceController`:

   ```
   import Foundation
   import WatchKit

   class GlanceInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

       override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {

           super.awakeWithContext(context)
       }
   }
   ```
4. Specify this custom class as the controller for your new Glance Interface Controller in interface builder:

   [image]

Build your app to an Apple Watch or to the simulator. The Glance won't appear in the glances until you turn it on in your Watch settings:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- First open your interface.storyboard
- Open utilities side bar (Right side of Xcode window)
- under the side bar choose Object Library (where you add UIImageView...etc in your app)
- Choose "Glance Interface Controller",
- drag and drop in your storyboard
- enjoy

[image]